# Optional method implementation in an abstract class

Tags: java, interface, java-8, abstract

I'm working on some framework and I got an abstract class, which should be implemented.

Now I got some other stuff the user should be able to configure, but it is optional.

So instead of the abstract method:

```
public abstract class AbstractModule {
    public void doSomething() {
        if (logMessage() != null)
            System.out.println(logMessage());
        doStuff();
    }

    protected abstract String logMessage(); // I'm optional
    protected abstract void doStuff();
}
```

I thought of just checking for an interface implementation:

```
public interface Log {
    String logMessage();
}

public abstract class AbstractModule {
    public void doSomething() {
        if (this instanceof Log) {
            if (((Log) this).logMessage() != null)
                System.out.println(((Log) this).logMessage());
        }
        doStuff();
    }

    protected abstract void doStuff();
}
```

So, if someone is implementing AbstractModule with the interface Log it would also show the message. The benefit for the implementer that I see: She doesn't need to care about implementing logMessage(), as it would be in the first example. Is this a valid approach or should it be done differently?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make the Logger a component of your module and define a default no-op logger in the abstract class. This way you get rid of the `instanceof` and still preserve the flexibility.

```
interface Log {
    void logMessage();
}

public abstract class AbstractModule {
    protected Log log;

    public AbstractModule(){
        this.log = () -> {};
    }

    public AbstractModule(Log log){
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void doSomething() {        
        log.logMessage();        
        doStuff();
    }

    protected abstract void doStuff();
}
```

Here is an example class extending `AbstractModule`:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule{

    public Module(){
        super(() -> System.out.println("message"));         
    }

    @Override
    protected void doStuff() {
        // do stuff     
    }   

}
```

You can define a getter-method for the logger in the abstract class if you want to expose the logger:

```
public Log getLogger(){
    return log;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this question has been tagged as `java-8`, an alternate solution would be to use an `interface` and `default` methods :

```
public interface Module {
    public default void doSomething() {
        if (logMessage() != null)
            System.out.println(logMessage());
        doStuff();
    }

    public default String logMessage() { return null; } // I'm optional
    public void doStuff();
}
```

*Usage :*

```
class NoLogModule implements Module {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() { }
}

class LogModule implements Module {

    @Override
    public void doStuff() { }

    @Override
    public String logMessage() { return "Message "; }

}
```

One advantage of using this approach instead of an *Abstract* class is that your class is now free to extend from another class. One disadvantage of this approach is that there is nothing you can do to stop someone from *overriding* the `doSomething` method (Based on your code, it doesn't look like you care about this)

Answer (score 2):

Reaching for `instanceof` is a bit of a code smell; there's normally a better way of doing it.

My first instinct is to have a no-op method in the base class:

```
class AbstractModule {
  final void doSomething() {
    maybeLogMessage();
  }

  void maybeLogMessage() {}
}
```

which obviously does nothing; but then you can override in a subclass:

```
class Subclass extends AbstractModule {
  @Override void maybeLogMessage() {
    System.out.println("The message");
  }
}
```

which would print the message.

If you don't want to repeat the `System.out.println` in all subclasses, you can return a special value from the method to indicate that it shouldn't be logged. For example, you can require the string to be non-empty:

```
class AbstractModule {
  final void doSomething() {
    String message = logMessage();
    if (!message.isEmpty()) { System.out.println(message); }
  }

  String logMessage() { return ""; }
}

class Subclass extends AbstractModule {
  @Override String logMessage() {
    return "The message";
  }
}
```